# Eigenvalues and eigenspaces for a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

What are the eigenvalues and eigenspaces for the linear transformation $$L:P(\mathbb R)\to P(\mathbb R),\,p(x)\to(1/x)\int_0^xp(t)dt$$

Using it as a characteristic polynomial doesn't work.

Comment: What is $P(\mathbb R)$? Is it the space of polynomials?

Comment: Hint: $P(x^k) = \frac{1}{k+1} x^k$ ...

Comment: @user251257 You mean $P(x) = \frac{1}{k+1} x^k$ ?

Comment: In your title is it eigenspaces or eigenvectors?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the classical technique $det(A-\lambda I)=0$ by restricting your operator to (stable) finite dimensional spaces $P_n$ (the space of polynomials with at most degree $n$).

Here is a more intrinsic solution. Let us turn back to the definition $L(p)=\lambda p$, i.e.,

$$\tag{0}(1/x)\int_0^x p(t)dt=\lambda p(x)$$

(note that we haven't written $p(t)$ but $p(x)$ on the RHS).

Before proceeding further, try polynomial $p(x)=x^n$. Do you see that it is an eigenfunction? Associated with which eigenvalue?

Now, are we sure that we have all eigenvectors in this way?

We must proceed to a systematic analysis. Here is how:

Multiply both sides by $x$:

$$\int_0^x p(t)dt = \lambda x p(x)$$

Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ (fundamental theorem of analysis); this implies (but is not equivalent to):

$$\tag{1}p(x)=\lambda(p(x)+xp'(x)) \ \ $$

For having equivalence we must add an initial condition which is $p(0)=0$ to  differential equation $(1)$.

Now, instead of using general methods for solving a differential equation, just plug in $(1)$ a general polynomial

$$p(x)=a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_nx^n$$

(you may have noted that $p(x)$ has no constant term. Why that?).

Up to you (begin by $n=1$, i.e., $p(x)=ax$)...

Remark: $(1)$ can be expressed in the following way:

$$\tag{2}x p'(x)=\mu p(x) \ \ \ \text{with} \ \ \ \mu:=\dfrac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}$$

connecting the initial problem with another one, simpler: the eigenvalues/eigenpolynomials of operator $L_1(p):=x p'(x)$.

Comment: It is simpler to look at $T(a_0 + a_1 x + \dotsc a_n x^n) = a_0 +  a_1/2 x + \dotsb + a_n/(n+1) x^n$ and argue by that the monomials is a basis.

Comment: @user251257 You are right, in this way, the operator, restricted to any finite dimensional subspace $P_n$ (degree at most $n$ polynomials) is at once diagonalized. I just wanted to go the farthest possible without referring to the fact that we had polynomials.

Comment: @user251257 see for example the remark I have placed at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $\lambda \neq 0$
$$\frac{1}{x}\int_0^xp(t)dt = \lambda p(x)  \Leftrightarrow \\
\int_0^x p(t)dt = \lambda x p(x)$$

Derivating both sides, and observing that both sides of the above equation vanish at $x=0$, you get that this is equivalent to 
$$p(x)= \lambda p(x) +\lambda x p'(x) \Leftrightarrow \\
\frac{(1-\lambda)}{\lambda}p(x)= x p'(x) \Leftrightarrow \\
\frac{(1-\lambda)}{\lambda} \frac{1}{x}=   \frac{p'(x)}{p(x)} \Leftrightarrow \\
\frac{(1-\lambda)}{\lambda} \ln(x)=   \ln(p(x)) \Leftrightarrow \\
p(x)=x^\frac{1-\lambda}{\lambda}
$$

Note that this is a polynomial if and only if $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ is a positive integer.